# $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ means flow commutes with left-translation

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-fields

Suppose $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ is a left invariant vector field on a Lie group G. In [this](http://montgomery.math.ucsc.edu/classes/mfds/LieAlgebras.pdf) article it mentions that

> The fact that our vector fields satisfy $L^*_gX = X$ implies that the
>   flow commutes with left-translation: $\Phi_t\circ L_g = L_g \circ
>  \Phi_t$.

It makes intuitive sense to me why this would be true, but I can't seem to formulate it.  Let $h\in G$, then we want to show $\Phi_X^t(L_g(h)) = g\cdot \Phi^t_X(h)$. We have $X_{h} = X_{L_{g^{-1}}(gh)}= L_{g^{-1}}^*(X_{gh})$, but now I am getting lost again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dt}{\frac{d}{dt}}$The strategy here is to show that $L_g \Phi_t L_g^{-1} = \Phi_t$ using the uniqueness of flow. Thus we differentiate the LHS at a point $p$ and time $t$, and replace the $\Phi_t$ with the flow of $L_g^* X$ (since the assumption is $L_g^* X = X$):

$$ \dt (L_g \Phi_t L_g^{-1} (p)) = dL_g (\dt \Phi_t (L_g^{-1} p))
 = dL_g (L_g^* X(\Phi_t L_g^{-1} p)).$$

Now, since $L_g^*X (h) = dL_g^{-1}(x(L_g h))$, this is simply $X(L_g\Phi_t L_g^{-1}p)$; i.e. we have shown $$\dt (L_g \Phi_t L_g^{-1} (p)) = X(L_g\Phi_t L_g^{-1}p).$$ Since $L_g\Phi_0L_g^{-1}$ is the identity, this says exactly that $L_g \Phi_t L_g^{-1}$ is the flow of $X$.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, why are we writing $L_g^*$ for the pushforward by $L_g$ when pushforward is usually written with a lower star?

Comment: @Eric: I use $L_g^*$ for the pullback and $dL_g$ for the pushforward... have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I think I'm struggling with $$\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_t(L_g^{-1}p)=L^*_gX(\Phi_t(L_g^{-1}p)).$$ (I added parentheses, I hope in the right place.) How do you get that?

Comment: @EricAuld: the fact that $\Phi_t$ is the flow of $X$ is $$\dt \Phi_t(h) = X(\Phi_t(h)).$$ Now use the fact $L_g^* X = X$ and choose $h=L_g^{-1} (p)$.